# Python: What is returned when I use requests.get('url') and print r.text?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape [this webpage](http://www.machinefinder.com/ww/en-US/categories/used-drawn-planters). This code works:

```
import requests
header = {
   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0',
}
r = requests.get('http://www.machinefinder.com/ww/en-US/categories/used-drawn-planters', headers=header)
print r.text
```

but I'm not sure what the text that it returns really is. I wish it was JSON so that I could copy other examples I've found that parse JSON.

Note: my work security blocks the webpage and says "Illegal Web Browser" when I use

```
header={ 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 
        }
```

which is why I'm using Firefox instead.

Comment: Check `r.headers['content-type']` for the type. Probably `text/html` if I had to guess.

Comment: You can get json back depending on the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>>>type(r.text) 
<type 'unicode'>
```

Looks to be the html for the page. You could use Beautiful soup to parse it 
:https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't get an arbitrary website to return a `JSON` formatted data unless it provides a wway to request (and get back..) a `JSON` formatted data.

`r.text` will generally hold the website's source code, unless again, it specifically returned `JSON` data.

So, you will have to resort to other means of parsing websites, such as BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thanks for the BeautifulSoup suggestion. I assumed that the issue wasn't with the website's ability to return `JSON` formatted data because [this guy on GitHub was able to do it.](https://github.com/thayton/machinefinder/blob/master/scraper.py)